# getting QSslError::CertificateNotYetValid on embedded device?

Tags: qt, networking, ssl

I implemented a https downloader,

I am getting QSsl error, QSslError::CertificateNotYetValid on embedded device, if I call ignoreErrors() from there download is working fine, but Same downloader is working fine from my ubuntu 9.04 without any sslerror().

I guess is,

--> Qt for embedded linux is not configured with openssl support, does anybody knows how to check it?

In case you think my guess is not correct, please provide your own.

Incase you want to take a look at code, It is over here,

http://pastebin.com/ffMFXxeW

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First check that the system date and time on the device are correct.

Comment: This seems to be the first bug, Thanks a lot for your help.